# What Happened To Disqus?

Tags: comments

I'm using Drupal 7.38 with the [Disqus](https://www.drupal.org/project/disqus) (version 7.x-1.12) module.

Disqus simply fails to load.  No trace of it in the console, elements or sources.

Disqus visibility is set to appear in  block as per `/admin/config/services/disqus` and block is configured. Its "permissions" are configured properly also.

Disqus was previously working.

Comment: Are you using an adblocker?

Comment: Have you applied any changes to site?

Comment: I am not using ad blocker.  I have made updates to core, etc. as they become available,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the disqusapi library to /sites/all/libraries (or a similar location)? This happened to my site. Our Disqus comment block stopped loading on existing nodes, and I could not turn on Disqus comments for new nodes.

Then I noticed the message in the Disqus config (/admin/config/services/disqus) that I needed to have the Libraries module installed and api files.

Once I added those files, the Disqus block loaded again.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  just now able to come back to this.  it seems like it could be the problem.  I do not have the library installed.  however, I'm not able to follow the documentation.  I'm really more of a website builder and admin of moderate skill.  lol

my assumption is to create a dir called disqus in /sites/all/libraries and install the library there, then unzip the library package there? do I need to make in config changes to point the module at the library?

Comment: I downloaded the disqusapi folder from https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php and put it right into /sites/all/libraries so that the path was /sites/all/libraries/disqusapi. I made sure the Libraries module was active, and the path to the library was automatically picked up by the Disqus module.

Comment: I got no joy.  Libraries module is active and I've confirmed the library is in /sites/all/libraries/disqusapi

I even ran update.php and cleared the caches...

Comment: actually it looks like it works on ONE content type, but not the rest it should.